# The right way to catch assertion failure in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, assert

I'm writing an integration tests for my database, and I've got one question. At the beginning of a test method I'm adding some objects to database and at the end of the method I should remove it.

So I've got a code like:

```
var group = new ContactGroup { Name = UserLogin + "_test_group" };
group.ID = _provider.AddGroup(UserLogin, group);
Assert.That(_provider.GetGroup(UserLogin, group.ID), Is.Not.Null);
_provider.RemoveGroup(UserLogin, group.ID);
```

The point is that if assertion fails, RemoveGroup won't be executed. What can I do about it?

If i try this:

```
var group = new ContactGroup { Name = UserLogin + "_test_group" };
group.ID = _provider.AddGroup(UserLogin, group);
try
{
    Assert.That(_provider.GetGroup(UserLogin, group.ID), Is.Not.Null);
}
finally
{
    _provider.RemoveGroup(UserLogin, group.ID);
}
```

should I rethrow AssertionException like this

```
catch (AssertionException)
{
    throw;
}
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to handle cleanup in database integration tests is to execute the test in a transaction, which is then rolled back once the test has completed.

Comment: Damn, it was so easy :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need at `catch` clause at all.  In C#, a `try {... throw ...} finally {...}` will execute the `finally` clause and then send the exception up the stack to the nearest `catch`, or out the top of the program if none.  Thus

```
try {
    Assert.Fail("BOOM!");
} finally {
    Cleanup();
}
```

will do exactly what you want: run `Cleanup()` and then die from the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the a tear down method. The tear down method is executed right after every test.

```
   [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
       _provider.RemoveGroup(UserLogin, group.ID);
    }
```

Comment: +1 There is also a tear-down for the class fixture, and another tear-down for the namespace.

Comment: I create this group only in selected methods. Is there any other way to manage this, because I don't want to create group when I don't need it (before each test)?

Answer (score 0):

The DBUnit people recomemend destorying on start up rather than shutdown ([Good setup don't need cleanup!](http://www.dbunit.org/bestpractices.html#nocleanup)) and is what I do. So the start of the test removes any data the test does not expect.